# Scala speed- Finding Primes example

Tags: performance, scala, testing, primes

I was looking at prime numbers with scala. I used the following code to check if a number n is prime.

```
(2 until n) forall(d=>n%d!=0)
```

I checked how fast scala will return true for the prime number `179426549`.

```
(2 until 179426549L.toInt) forall(d=>179426549L%d!=0)
res22: Boolean = true
```

Then I tried an even bigger number `32416190071` to see how long it will take to return true for this larger prime.

```
(2 until 32416190071L.toInt) forall(d=>32416190071L%d!=0)
res23: Boolean = true
```

To my surprise, a return value of true came back for the larger prime much faster. Why is it that the larger number returned a true so much faster?

Answer (score 6):

The larger number, 32416190071, [overflows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow) the maximum positive value that can be stored in an integer and becomes the negative number -1943548297. The range `(2 until -1943548297)` is empty so the `forall` returns true immediately.